# Templates have changed after switching wordpress themes

Tags: php, wordpress

i was trying to look at different wordpress themes but when i changed them the template would not be correct. For example i was on zerif, changed to another theme and back, and it was no longer the same. Instead it had a 'hello' post on the home page'. Not sure why this is. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: check your static page

Comment: This would be better suited for the wordpress support forums.

Answer (score 0):

After change theme you must select static page and menu.
[select static page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmUa4.png)

Comment: I can't find the static page button anywhere for some reason. It is not under settings - reading as yours is.